# Find Regex for Given Format that matches specific key value pair(s) in JSON

Tags: java, python, json, regex

> '{"id":1,"last":"Doe","first":"John","location":{"city":"Oakland","state":"CA","postalCode":"94607"},"active":true}',
>   '{"id":2,"last":"Doe","first":"Jane","location":{"city":"San
>   Francisco","state":"WA","postalCode":"94105"},"active":false}',
>   '{"id":3,"last":"Doe","first":"Jane","location":{"city":"San
>   Francisco","state":"CA","postalCode":"94105"},"active":true}'

I am looking for getting json contain which includes '{"id":1}'. OR
I am looking for getting json contain which includes '{"location":{"state":"CA"},"active":true}' Likewise...

So for '{"id":1}' it should return

> {{"id":1,"last":"Doe","first":"John","location":{"city":"Oakland","state":"CA","postalCode":"94607"},"active":true}

and for '{"location":{"state":"CA"},"active":true}' it should return

> {"id":1,"last":"Doe","first":"John","location":{"city":"Oakland","state":"CA","postalCode":"94607"},"active":true}
>   {"id":3,"last":"Doe","first":"Jane","location":{"city":"San
>   Francisco","state":"CA","postalCode":"94105"},"active":true}

Comment: Why is this tagged both `java` and `python`? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Any json parser might just work for you. Google jackson/gson.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one: `(.*"state":"CA".*"active":true.*)`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/hP6gS1/238

It works.

You can change tag name and values as per your requirements. It extracts your required JSON content.

Answer (score 0):

Python version

```
my_json = """[
    {
       "id": 1,
       "last": "Doe",
       "first": "John",
       "location": {
          "city": "Oakland",
          "state": "CA",
          "postalCode": "94607"
       },
       "active": true
    }, {
       "id": 2,
       "last": "Doe",
       "first": "Jane",
       "location": {
          "city": "San Francisco",
          "state": "WA",
          "postalCode": "94105"
       },
       "active": false
    }, {
       "id": 3,
       "last": "Doe",
       "first": "Jane",
       "location": {
          "city": "San Francisco",
          "state": "CA",
          "postalCode": "94105"
       },
       "active": true
    }
]"""

import json
my_list = json.loads(my_json)
result_list = list(filter(
        lambda d:
            d["id"] == 1 or \
            (d["location"]["state"] == "CA" and d["active"]),
        my_list
        ))
```

Comment: if you want to return as a json, use `json.dumps(result_list)`.